# What is the significance of default in open brush contracts traits implementation?

Tags: polkadot, ink, openbrush

I was going through the code of open brush implementation for different tokens, and was confused at a point in PSP22 contract where there is a word written `default`, as shown below

```
default fn _emit_transfer_event(&self, _from: Option<AccountId>, _to: Option<AccountId>, _amount: Balance) {}
```

which is the implementation of a trait, so here i was not able to understand why `default` word is used.

Some questions that are in my mind:

- Is it used to as `Default` keyword used in rust or something else?
- Is it defined in open brush to be used by itself?
- If it is defined in open brush please do point to its implementation.

The reference to the git repo for the same can be find [here](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/blob/96b556536a9806cb2a0db7a6159a412754ceba9b/contracts/src/token/psp22/psp22.rs#L129-L306).

Answer (score 2):

[specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210) is Rust feature that allows you to override a default implementation (if the `method` or `impl` is "specialized" with the [default](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md#the-default-keyword) keyword). It's like `virtual` in c# and C++

So you define a Trait and a generic implementation in a crate and within the contract you implement this Trait. If this impl block is empty {}, *specialization* will implement the most specific implementation, which is the one you defined in the file. Every generic implementation in Openbrush (PSP22, PSP34, ..) uses the `default` keyword that makes these functions **overrideable**.

without the `default` keyword you can not *override* the function body when implementing the Trait